# ImageMagick convert black image into a different colour

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a black SVG image into a coloured one. i.e replace black with a given colour. I've tried:

`convert -resize 256x256\> -fill 'red' original.svg -opaque black new.png`

This kind of works:

[image]

As you can see though, it has a black border still. How do I get rid of that?

I tried to upload the original SVG, but it won't let me (doesn't accept the format). But this is how it looks when I just do a straight:

`convert original.svg new.png`

[image]

**UPDATE:** I just found I can set the fill and border using in the main SVG:

`<svg stroke="red" fill="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512">`

But thats not ideal, as I would need to open the SVG, edit with a regex to the values I want, save it, and then finally do the conversion - so a bit long winded :)

The SVG I'm testing it with is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><!-- Font Awesome Free 5.15.4 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License) --><path d="M633.82 458.1L494.97 350.78c.52-5.57 1.03-11.16 1.03-16.87 0-111.76-99.79-153.34-146.78-311.82-7.94-28.78-49.44-30.12-58.44 0-15.52 52.34-36.87 91.96-58.49 125.68L45.47 3.37C38.49-2.05 28.43-.8 23.01 6.18L3.37 31.45C-2.05 38.42-.8 48.47 6.18 53.9l588.36 454.73c6.98 5.43 17.03 4.17 22.46-2.81l19.64-25.27c5.41-6.97 4.16-17.02-2.82-22.45zM144 333.91C144 432.35 222.72 512 320 512c44.71 0 85.37-16.96 116.4-44.7L162.72 255.78c-11.41 23.5-18.72 48.35-18.72 78.13z"/></svg>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok, a REALLY dirty hack - but seems to do the trick. In my script, I'm now cloning the SVG into a temp file, running `sed` on it to change the fill/stroke colour, and then converting into a PNG at full size:

```
cp youtube-square.svg foo.svg
sed -i 's/<svg /<svg stroke="green" fill="green" /g' foo.svg
convert foo.svg foo.png
```

A bit clunky for my liking, but it seems to work :)

Comment: -stroke 'red' perhaps

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, but no joy :( (still has the black background). Is there a way to edit the SVG before converting it? i.e change black to whatever colour, then convert

Comment: sure it's just text, use any editor you like. We probably need the SVG to help further. You should be able to paste the SVG into the question if it's not too long.

Comment: @RobertLongson just updated the question, with the SVG inline. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertLongson I think I found a clunky way to do it (see my modified question).

Comment: In original question the problem is that the red fill i not the same as a fill color in SVG. The command will find the black areas of the image and color them red -- and then there is a problem with antialias between the black color and the background. This can be handled using `-fuzz 50%` -- of a percentage that matches the case. But I also see this as a "hack".

Comment: Is this part of a larger collection of SVGs and a batch process or is it just a onetime/one image thing?

Comment: Post the original SVG. Your black image is a PNG already.

Comment: @fmw42 I did already (inline as text,as SO doesn't let you upload SVGs)

Comment: @chrwahl its a batch of 500+ SVGs (icons), that I want to convert into PNGs so that I can  add them into a CSS sprite without hundreds of unneeded ones :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby in that case I will suggest that you follow the XSL approach that I lay out in my answer. Consider combining all icons into one SVG document either by reference or embed them (maybe embed them now that you need to convert with ImageMagic). Then you have the entire sprite sheet in one SVG.

Comment: @Andrew Newby You can zip the SVG file and upload the zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an XSL transformation on the SVG before converting with ImageMagic.

Given XML (original.svg):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
  <!-- Font Awesome Free 5.15.4 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License) -->
  <path d="M633.82 458.1L494.97 350.78c.52-5.57 1.03-11.16 1.03-16.87 0-111.76-99.79-153.34-146.78-311.82-7.94-28.78-49.44-30.12-58.44 0-15.52 52.34-36.87 91.96-58.49 125.68L45.47 3.37C38.49-2.05 28.43-.8 23.01 6.18L3.37 31.45C-2.05 38.42-.8 48.47 6.18 53.9l588.36 454.73c6.98 5.43 17.03 4.17 22.46-2.81l19.64-25.27c5.41-6.97 4.16-17.02-2.82-22.45zM144 333.91C144 432.35 222.72 512 320 512c44.71 0 85.37-16.96 116.4-44.7L162.72 255.78c-11.41 23.5-18.72 48.35-18.72 78.13z"/>
</svg>
```

And the following XSL where I add a fill and stroke attribute to `<svg>` (convert.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  exclude-result-prefixes="svg">
  <xsl:template match="svg:svg">
    <svg>
      <xsl:attribute name="fill">
        <xsl:value-of select="'red'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="stroke">
        <xsl:value-of select="'none'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This command:

```
xsltproc convert.xsl original.svg | convert - new.png
```

Will pipe the transformed SVG into ImageMagic and generate the PNG.

You can also use parameters in XSL, so here is a variation of the above:

A parameter is added to the XSL.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  exclude-result-prefixes="svg">

  <xsl:param name="fill" select="'red'" />
  
  <xsl:template match="svg:svg">
    <svg>
      <xsl:attribute name="fill">
        <xsl:value-of select="$fill"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="stroke">
        <xsl:value-of select="'none'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And using the command:

```
xsltproc --stringparam fill green convert.xsl original.svg | convert - new.png
```

can change the fill of the PNG (and SVG) to green.

Answer (score 2):

In Imagemagick, you can change your black SVG to a red PNG as follows. Here I use your black.png since you have not provided the black.svg file. The following is Unix syntax of Imagemagick.

[image]

```
convert black.png \
\( -clone 0 -fill red -colorize 100 \) \
\( -clone 0 -negate \) \
-compose over -composite \
black2red.png
```

[image]

Comment: For an image I have (the GitHub logo), this was only coloring the edges of the colored areas. To have the colored area filled in red, I had to remove the second `-clone` argument: `convert github_logo.png \( -clone 0 -fill red -colorize 100 \) -compose over -composite github_logo_red.png`.